# Find the value of a div id based on partial match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several divs on a page. They are formatted like:

```
<div id='profile-1'></div>
<div id='profile-2'></div>
<div id='profile-3'></div>
<div id='profile-4'></div>
```

I need to find the value of the div with the highest id. In the previous example it would be "profile-4" (because 4 is the highest).

I've figured out how to search through the divs by using:

```
var elements = $('[id^=profile-]')
```

This returns an object. I need to take that object and figure out that "profile-4" is the highest and if possible extract the value "4".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
var highest = 0;
$('[id^=profile-]').each(function(){
   var id = parseInt(this.id.split('-')[1], 10);
   highest = id > highest ? id : highest;
});

alert(highest); // 4
```

This will work even if you have different order eg:

```
<div id='profile-1'></div>
<div id='profile-20'></div>
<div id='profile-3'></div>
<div id='profile-4'></div>
```

In this case, `20` will be alerted.

Comment: You've forgot an essential part - casting to integers. Add <div id='profile-14'></div> and check the result :)

Comment: @Cheery: Didn't check it actually :) Updated now. Thanks

Comment: @JasonSmall: The answer has been updated, make sure you update it. BTW, here is working example: http://jsbin.com/awevum

Answer (score 2):

Here is just another way to do it: if the the `div`'s are always in ascending order (like in your HTML snippet you provided), you can do this:

```
$('div[id^=profile-]').get().reverse()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@Sarfraz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051264/464744), you can use `map` to build beautifully obfuscated code:

```
var highest = Math.max.apply(null, $('[id^="profile-"]').map(function() {
  return [parseInt(this.id.split('-')[1], 10)];
}));

console.log(highest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var highest = Math.max.apply(null, $.map($('[id^=profile-]'), function(el) {
    return el.id.split('-')[1];
});)

var highest_div = $('#profile-'+highest);
```